# count of element in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

```
...
<element>
    <e:Element1 xmlns:e="mynamespace" > ... </.. >
    <e:Element1 xmlns:e="mynamespace" > ... </.. >
    <e:Element1 xmlns:e="mynamespace" > ... </.. >
    <a/>
</element>
...
```

and this XPath:

`//*[local-name()='element']/count(*)` return 4 what is OK.
but now I wanna know count of element1 what is 3. I try a lot of possibilities but with no succes. I have to use local-name and `namespace-uri()`

Comment: What do you mean by "I wanna count of element1"? I don't understand that.

Comment: sorry I hope now it is correct.

Comment: No, still don't get it. What is a "count of element1"?

Comment: count, number, it should return 3

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
count(//element/Element1[namespace-uri()='mynamespace'])
```

Comment: Possibly count(//element/Element1[@e='mynamespace'])

Comment: lol I am so stupid thx a lot count should go first count(//*[local-name()='element']/*[local-name()=Element1 and namespace-uri=....)

Comment: Where do I import count() from?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using XPath from an environment such as Java or C#, you should first bind a prefix to the namespace, which depends on the API you are using, but will be something like

```
xpath.declareNamespace("f", "mynamespace")
```

and then evaluate the XPath expression

```
count(element/f:Element1)
```

I deliberately chose a different prefix from the one in your source document just to show that you can use any prefix you like, but of course your code is more readable if you are consistent in your choice of prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

For the following valid XML

```
<element>
  <e:Element1 xmlns:e="mynamespace"></e:Element1>
  <e:Element1 xmlns:e="mynamespace"></e:Element1>
  <e:Element1 xmlns:e="mynamespace"></e:Element1>
  <a/>
</element>
```

this XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:e="mynamespace">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(element/e:Element1)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives the desired output of **3**.

The selector is qualified with the correct namespace.

You were close in your question and you could drop the namespace and use the following XSL instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(element/*[local-name()='Element1'])"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```