# Looping in Xpath Expression having Namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodes, xml-namespaces

Suppose this my Sample XML with Namespaces

```
<data>
    <vnfr:vnfr-catalog xmlns:vnfr="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:nfvo:vnfr">
        <vnfr:vnfr>
            <vnfr:id>1234</vnfr:id>
                <vnfr:vdur>
                    <vnfr:id>987</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:id>987</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:management-ip>10.100.100.10</vnfr:management-ip>
                </vnfr:vdur>
                <vnfr:vdur>
                    <vnfr:id>567</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:id>567</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:management-ip>10.100.100.11</vnfr:management-ip>
                </vnfr:vdur>
        </vnfr:vnfr>
    </vnfr:vnfr-catalog>
</data>
```

I have a sample Xpath expression which I use in Java

```
expression="/data/*[local-name() = 'vnfr-catalog']/*[local-name() = 'vnfr']/*[local-name() = 'id']/*[local-name() = 'vdur']/*[local-name() = 'management-ip']/text()";
```

Output: 10.100.100.10

But how to Iterate and fetch the 2nd management-ip i.e. 10.100.100.11

I tried the below expression with vdur[2] , but it didn't worked.

```
expression="/data/*[local-name() = 'vnfr-catalog']/*[local-name() = 'vnfr']/*[local-name() = 'id']/*[local-name() = 'vdur[2]']/*[local-name() = 'management-ip']/text()";
```

How to fetch the 2nd management IP using expression??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has two mistakes:

1. You should not get into `id` element since it does not contain `management-ip`, they are on the same level of hierarchy
2. `*[local-name() = 'vdur[2]']` should be replaced with `*[local-name() = 'vdur'][2]`

Below is my query that seems working:

```
/data/vnfr:vnfr-catalog/vnfr:vnfr/vnfr:vdur[2]/vnfr:management-ip/text()
```

This is tested on

```
<data xmlns:vnfr="asdasdas">
    <vnfr:vnfr-catalog>
        <vnfr:vnfr>
            <vnfr:id>1234</vnfr:id>
                <vnfr:vdur>
                    <vnfr:id>987</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:id>987</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:management-ip>10.100.100.10</vnfr:management-ip>
                </vnfr:vdur>
                <vnfr:vdur>
                    <vnfr:id>567</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:id>567</vnfr:id>
                    <vnfr:management-ip>10.100.100.11</vnfr:management-ip>
                </vnfr:vdur>
        </vnfr:vnfr>
    </vnfr:vnfr-catalog>
</data>
```

Above is your example but amended a bit since you are not declaring the namespace.

Output:

```
Text='10.100.100.11'
```

Tested in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Your correct query would look like this:

```
/data/*[local-name() = 'vnfr-catalog']/*[local-name() = 'vnfr']/*[local-name() = 'vdur'][2]/*[local-name() = 'management-ip']/text()
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be done with the xPath namespaces ignored. That's not working!!!

Comment: @Tushar see the last line of my answer. Also check you mistakes from the top of my answer

Comment: Ok Got it......But one doubt how to find the length of "vdur" attribute available in the given XML by Java?????

Comment: Don't ask supplementary questions in comments. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexey resolve your one issue. below is the answer to getting the length of an attribute

```
While xxx is the tag prefix, use just count(//Formulas/yyy)
```

Use count keyword

Source

[count of element in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393541/count-of-element-in-xpath)

Hope it will help you :)